# Tensorflow image_dataset_from_directory split to train, validation, testing

Tags: tensorflow, dataset

I have a data set containing pictures in 2 classes.
The dataset is organized in 1 folder that contains 2 folders, 1 for each class.
class 1 pictures path: "Project\Class_A"
class 2 pictures path: "Project\Class_B"

I want to read all the data (quickly).
splitting it into train, validation, test.
train a tensorflow model.

I saw that the image_dataset_from_directory function doing the trick nicely but I can not found how to split to a test dataset (only train, validation).
I want the data to be splitted randomly (and not just split it manually by moving some pictures to a different folder).

Do you have any idea for a quick way to read all the data and splitting it to train, validation, test datasets?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue: my goal would be to test my model with different validation and test splits. I can change the seed for the train/validation set, but for the test set I had to move some of my images to a different folder manually and create an additional flow from the test directory like this:

`(ds_test = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(directory = PATH_TO_DATASET_TEST,...)`, so it is not convenient if I want to use a different test split. Any ideas?

Comment: Might be late to the party, but this SO answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71129505