# Is it possible to split a tensorflow dataset into train, validation AND test datasets when using image_dataset_from_directory?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets, tf.keras

I am using `tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory` to load a dataset of 4575 images. While this function allows to split the data into two subsets (with the `validation_split` parameter), I want to split it into training, testing, and validation subsets.

I have tried using `dataset.skip()` and `dataset.take()` to further split one of the resulting subsets, but these functions return a `SkipDataset` and a `TakeDataset` respectively (by the way, contrary to [the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset?version=stable#take), where it is claimed that these functions return a `Dataset`). This leads to problems when fitting the model - the metrics calculated on validation sets (val_loss, val_accuracy) disappear from model history.

So, my question is: is there a way to split a `Dataset` into three subsets for training, validation and testing, so that all three subsets are also `Dataset` objects?

**Code used to load the data**

```
def load_data_tf(data_path: str, img_shape=(256,256), batch_size: int=8):
    train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
        data_path,
        validation_split=0.2,
        subset="training",
        label_mode='categorical',
        seed=123,
        image_size=img_shape,
        batch_size=batch_size)
    val_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
        data_path,
        validation_split=0.3,
        subset="validation",
        label_mode='categorical',
        seed=123,
        image_size=img_shape,
        batch_size=batch_size)
    return train_ds, val_ds

train_dataset, test_val_ds = load_data_tf('data_folder', img_shape = (256,256), batch_size=8)
test_dataset = test_val_ds.take(686)
val_dataset = test_val_ds.skip(686)
```

**Model compilation and fitting**

```
model.compile(optimizer='sgd',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=50, validation_data=val_dataset, verbose=1)
```

**When using a normal `Dataset`, `val_accuracy` and `val_loss` are present in the history of the model:**

[image: Expected behaviour: when using a Dataset, validation metrics are calculated]

**But when using a `SkipDataset`, they are not:**

[image: Using the SkipDataset produced by test_val_ds.take() leads to validation metrics disappearing from model history]

[image: val_accuracy and val_loss are not present in history keys when using a SkipDataset or a TakeDataset]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you are not taking and skipping samples when you do `test_val_ds.take(686)` and `test_val_ds.skip(686)`, but actually batches. Try running `print(val_dataset.cardinality())` and you will see how many batches you really have reserved for validation. I am guessing `val_dataset` is empty, because you do not have 686 batches for validation. Here is a working example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import pathlib

dataset_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz"
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file('flower_photos', origin=dataset_url, untar=True)
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)

batch_size = 32

train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(180, 180),
  batch_size=batch_size)

val_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(180, 180),
  batch_size=batch_size)

test_dataset = val_ds.take(5)
val_ds = val_ds.skip(5)

print('Batches for testing -->', test_dataset.cardinality())
print('Batches for validating -->', val_ds.cardinality())

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=(180, 180, 3)),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(5)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

epochs=1
history = model.fit(
  train_ds,
  validation_data=val_ds,
  epochs=1
)
```

```
Found 3670 files belonging to 5 classes.
Using 2936 files for training.
Found 3670 files belonging to 5 classes.
Using 734 files for validation.
Batches for testing --> tf.Tensor(5, shape=(), dtype=int64)
Batches for validating --> tf.Tensor(18, shape=(), dtype=int64)
92/92 [==============================] - 96s 1s/step - loss: 1.3516 - accuracy: 0.4489 - val_loss: 1.1332 - val_accuracy: 0.5645
```

In this example, with a `batch_size` of 32, you can clearly see that the validation set reserved 23 batches. Afterwards, 5 batches were given to the test set and 18 batches remained for the validation set.

Comment: yes, this does work, thank you! I never thought that `count` in `take()` represents the number of batches, not individual elements.

Comment: How do you know `take` and `skip` are taking and skipping the same files/images?

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment, so have to answer to [JeffreyShran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4373967/jeffreyshran) about how we can be sure about `take` and `skip` taking the same pictures in that block. Here is the check code:

```py
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(10)
take = int(len(dataset)/2)

test = dataset.take(take)
print('test:', list(test.as_numpy_iterator()))
dataset = dataset.skip(take)
print('valid:', list(dataset.as_numpy_iterator()))
```

We get:

```py
test: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
valid: [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I'm a newcomer, so my apologies if I'm writing not in the appropriate place. But I think that consideration above must have been proved.

Comment: Does this solve the question? Or are you trying to ask JeffreyShran questions about their comment on AloneTogether's answer?

Comment: Just move the code to the comments under JeffreyShran question if you are able and delete my 'answer'. I can't understand this restriction to comment if you do not have 'reputation', that was the reason I had to write in the not appropriate place - there is just no other choice to leave the comments for the newcomers like me.